# update markers when not watched

Tags: angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive, ui-leaflet

In [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) is there a way how to update markers and paths on the map when we switch off the $watch using `markersWatchOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are look for something similar to this example:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/examples/0000-viewer.html#/mixed/overlays-markers-nested-no-watch-example

In which, markers are updated via getDirectiveControls().

There is more about it in this issue:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-leaflet/issues/239

Comment: I have already found this page and that was really it. I only forgot to close this question. Anyways, thank you, this will somebody for sure. ;-)

Comment: @zatziky you should also close your issue: https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/1075

Comment: @CaioIglesias Closed!